# What number goes in the ?? box?

Tags: pattern, no-computers, number-property

A simple pattern puzzle

What is the number in the ?? box? Why?  No programming please.

[image]

Comment: I assume the off-by-one-error when trying the obvious solution is intentional?

Comment: Yep @Sleafar it is

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing number is

> 34

To get the value in a box from its two preceding inputs, you

> take the product of all of the digits of each input, and then sum these together.  For example, 3x6x6 + 2x4x2 = 108 + 16 = 124.  To get the missing value, we see that 5x6 + 2x2 = 30 + 4 = 34.

Comment: correct, you were 1 minute faster

Comment: So wjy not "Clear the least signifcant bit and take the difference"? Gives the exact same result and is arguably simpler.

Comment: @loopywalt I'd say "Clear the least signifcant bit" is an extra rule  and making an exception for only one number to make it fit, which is 'ugly'. The accepted answer has one rule that fits all. Also, it seems clear to me that something completely different for the almost matching 'difference' rule is sought.

Comment: @Retudin an exception is something that explicitly references a small percentage of something. Prescribing a fixed precision for everything hardly qualifies for that. Also how do you "count" rules? It's a pretty ill-defined concept as long as you do not account for complexity. The apparently intended answer is a rather complex,arbitrary rule without any justification beyond its happenening to match a small sample

Comment: I checked with my six year old and he didn't agree that "clear the least significant bit" was simpler.

Comment: My seven year old politely reminds your six year old that there is a differencee between "easy" and "simple".

Comment: My six year old stands by his statement. There's nothing simpler about your proposed alternate solution.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to apologise. For some reason this kind of puzzle never fails to annoy the sh** out of me. But obviously there is no point in being so negative/smart-arse/judgemental about what's after all just a bit of fun.

Comment: No worries. For clarity, I don't think your solution works anyway.  Wouldn't your procedure put a 28 in the box, which would fail to produce a 14 at the next step?

Comment: No, it just "flats" 21 to 20 and remains others unchanged.